# Calculate double integral using polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Let $f(x,y) = x^2\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$ and domain $D = \{(x,y) : x^2 +y^2 \le 4 \ , 0\le y\le x\}$. Find value of

$$\iint_D f(x,y) \ dx dy$$

I tried to use $x = r\cos \theta$ , $y = r\sin \theta$ and then got:
$$\iint_Df(x,y)\,dxdy=\int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{2} (r^3\cos^2\theta)\cdot r\,drd\theta =\frac{\pi +2 }{8}\cdot\frac{32}{5}$$

I don't know whether this answer is correct or not.

Comment: What did you get after the change of variables? Can you show your work?

Comment: @Jack I added my efforts.

Comment: WA agrees with your answer

Comment: @Gabe Can you send the link, please?

Comment: [first region](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+x%5E2+*+sqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2Csqrt%282%29%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2Cx%7D) and [second region](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+x%5E2+*+sqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2C+%7Bx%2Csqrt%282%29%2C2%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2Csqrt%284-x%5E2%29%7D) splitting it into two regions as WA only supports definite bounds

Comment: @S.H.W your answer is correct, but you can simplify it as $\frac{4}{5}(\pi+2)$.